# the value of Resultset while getting now rows form database

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

i want to know that while firing the select query from database in java(JDBC).suppose that 
the execute(Query) return no rows then what will be thae value of Resultset object??? is it null or can be other ??? Reply please

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select * from people");
```

Comment: what did you get when you ran this, assuming people table is empty?

Comment: Shouldn't be null, its empty. You can always run the code and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Execute Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) , it states

> a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; never null

So the result set is empty not null

Answer (score 1):

See Javadocs for [Statement Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) it is clearly mentioned that executeQuery never returns null. If there are no rows to fetch then it will return an empty resultset.